# Resize Apache Aurora's Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, mesos, apache-aurora

Trying out Apache Aurora, i see in my vagrant at 192.168.33.7, mesos indicated my vm parameters as 1gb of ram and 19.5 Gb of available disk.
Is there anything i can do to resize and augment those resources?
I already try changing the ram in the Vagrantfile and resize the disk with VBoxManage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change [Mesos resources](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/#examples) with following configuration:

```
--resources='cpus:24;gpus:2;mem:24576;disk:409600;ports:[21000-24000,30000-34000]'
```